# Can you show me an example of using "System.gc()" to free the memory allocated by new Object in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The method is about like this :

```
public void testGc() {
    char c[] = new char[1024*1024*100] // Allocate 100M memory
    System.gc();
}
```

But after the method returns, the memory allocated won't be free.

Comment: You still have a reference to the array...

Comment: The whole point of garbage collection is NOT to manually worry about freeing memory. Also, the scope of `c` is not finished yet, so it is not eligible for garbage collection yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you still have a reference so it won't be freed.

second: calling `System.gc()` won't free the memory instantly. It just kindly asks the garbage collector if it could clean up.

Comment: Imagine I have function that declares a lot of memory, when the function is called the memory will be occupied.
When the the call ends, will the memory be reversed afterwords or not ?

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  ok();
  Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
  n.nextLine();
 }
 
 private static void ok(){
  char c[] = new char[1024*1024*200]; // Allocate 100M memory
  Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
  n.nextLine();
 }

Comment: no. not immediatly